# Formatting numbered list of code blocks in Markdown

Tags: markdown

Is it possible to make a numbered list of code blocks in Markdown? This is a list where each list item is a code block; there is no other text.

If it is possible, how? If not, why?

My use case, for anyone curious about context, is formatting coding exercises in a tutorial. Some exercises ask the reader to look at multiple code examples. These coding examples are presented in a numbered list. They need to be numbered as these numbers will be used to refer to the section of the exercise.

#### Edit

I am using [Remarkable](https://remarkableapp.github.io/index.html) with Github-flavored Markdown. I am now wondering if my issue could be related to this particular software, because I attempted the working example in @dxiv's answer and got a divergent result. I can see their Markdown works in the StackOverflow comment, but Remarkable renders it with the code blocks missing newlines. For example:

```
abc
def
```

...is the expected output, but Remarkable renders as:

```
abc def
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following appears to work, see [source](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63081238/edit) for the raw text in all cases.

````
1. ```
   abc
   def
   ```
````

For example.

1. ```
   abc
   def
   ```
2. ```
   123
   456
   ```
3. With a title.

   ```
   ghi
   jkl
   ```

- Bulleted.

  ```
  mno
  pqr
  ```

---

[ *EDIT* ]   Seeing that Remarkable has an online demo, that one appears to render lists of code blocks similarly to SO above, see for example [this snippet](https://jonschlinkert.github.io/remarkable/demo/#md64=JTdCJTIyc291cmNlJTIyOiUyMjEuJTIwJTYwJTYwJTYwJTVDbiUyMCUyMCUyMGFiYyU1Q24lMjAlMjAlMjAlMjBkJTVDbiUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMGUlNUNuJTIwJTIwJTIwZmdoJTVDbiUyMCUyMCUyMCU2MCU2MCU2MCU1Q24lNUNuMi4lMjAlNjAlNjAlNjAlNUNuJTIwJTIwJTIwMTIzJTVDbiUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMDQlNUNuJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwNSU1Q24lMjAlMjAlMjA2NzglNUNuJTIwJTIwJTIwJTYwJTYwJTYwJTVDbiUyMiwlMjJkZWZhdWx0cyUyMjolN0IlMjJodG1sJTIyOmZhbHNlLCUyMnhodG1sT3V0JTIyOmZhbHNlLCUyMmJyZWFrcyUyMjpmYWxzZSwlMjJsYW5nUHJlZml4JTIyOiUyMmxhbmd1YWdlLSUyMiwlMjJsaW5raWZ5JTIyOnRydWUsJTIybGlua1RhcmdldCUyMjolMjIlMjIsJTIydHlwb2dyYXBoZXIlMjI6dHJ1ZSwlMjJfaGlnaGxpZ2h0JTIyOnRydWUsJTIyX3N0cmljdCUyMjpmYWxzZSwlMjJfdmlldyUyMjolMjJodG1sJTIyJTdEJTdE) (link was too long to post in a comment).

Comment: I was not able to get the same result with my editor, leading me to think it is perhaps an issue with the editor (Remarkable)? I added details to my question.

Comment: @cheryllium This certainly depends on the editor and (pre)viewer. The markdown-preview in atom, for example, shows the code blocks next to the numbers/bullets, indented correctly and with all the line breaks, but the number/bullet itself gets vertically aligned towards the bottom of the block instead of at the top like SO shows it. As for Remarkable, I don't know and can't try it since I am on Windows and their Windows version is not out, yet.

Comment: @cheryllium Or maybe there is some difference/setting in the standalone Remarkable vs. the online one, see the edit I just added at the end.